# LINQ select List where sub-list contains item from another list

Tags: c#, linq

I can't wrap my head around how to create this query. I need to select the items in List 1, if the items Cats list contains a Cat object matching the ID of one of the Cats in List2. Is this possible? Thank you

```
List1<pet> List1 = new List<pet>(100);
List2<cat> List2 = new List<cat>(30);

//populate lists, some of the items in List2 (cat) will be in the List1 items Cats list

//classes
class pet{
   string ID;
   List<cat> Cats;
}

class cat {
   string ID;
   string name;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just use following LINQ expression:

```
List1.Where(p => p.Cats.Any(c => List2.Any(c2 => c2.ID == c.ID)));
```

You should also be able to do that with intersect (That is if your classes have their `Equals` methods overriden to check for matching IDs - see [Intersect on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
List1.Where(p => p.Cats.Intersect(List2).Any())
```

Comment: I have my equals method overridden to check for matching ID's, which is more efficient?

Comment: Intersect one would be faster in those cases where there are no matches (Any will have to go through the entire collection anyway). Any is going to be faster when there are lots of possible matches (because it stops after just one found match). I only gave you the Intersect variant because it looks prettier in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, yours and Alexanders are both working well!

Answer (score 4):

This should work with nested `Any`:

```
var result = List1.Where(p => List2.Any(l => p.Cats.Any(c => c.ID == l.ID)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var naughtycats = List1.Where(pet => List2.Select(cat => cat.ID).Contains(pet.ID));
```

Comment: Using select does extra work - you'll convert every object into it's ID before checking but you only need one match. Using Any() is optimal in this case.