# How can we select fields from one list i.e. List<TEntity> on the basis of fields in another list i.e. List<string>

Tags: c#, list, .net-core

I am trying to select only the matching fields from one list i.e. List<TEntity> on the basis of fields in another list i.e. List<string>.

```
var list = new List<TEntity>();
// Code for populating the list. Let's say this holds list data like: Id, Name, Type, Address, Department
var columns = commaSeparatedcolumns.Split(',').ToList();//commaSeparatedcolumns: "Id, Address, Department"
// Need to return list with only matched fields. In this case those matched fields will be: Id, Address, Department
// Tried following approach but had no success:
list.Where(x => columns.Any(y => y.Equals(x)));
```

Can someone please provide any clue?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: can you show us your attempts?

Comment: Can you show those attempts? Then we may be able to explain what went wrong

Comment: We do not know your selection criteria. How are the fields stored in the `List<string>`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814049/linq-select-list-where-sub-list-contains-item-from-another-list

Comment: You can't vary the number of columns returned from a query, only rows